# Ubuntu 14.10 cannot connect to Wired Network from my Desktop

Tags: 14.10, network-manager, ethernet

I upgraded my Ubuntu version to 14.10 and all of a sudden it won't connect to Internet at all.
This is my Desktop and after upgrade it shows a wireless icon in the network manager panel

Here are some info from network related files.

```
lspci -nm | grep 0200

  02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co, Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)

  $cat /etc/network/interfaces
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp

  auto eth0
  eth0 inet dhcp

  $sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep -i version
  Version: 1.138.1

  $dmesg | grep -e rtl -e rate.c
```

Really Appreciate any help?

Comment: got any solution?